# secure url to avoid direct call

Tags: php, apache

I want to protect my URL to avoid direct call or re use on any modification. How can i créate a  uniq id in my url and check it apache?

in my vhost :

```
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !phptoken
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) http://accessdenied.com

ProxyPass         /  http://192.168.0.100:8080/ nocanon
ProxyPassReverse  /  http://192.168.0.100:8080/
```

If the token is ok, i redirect to my tomcat. but for now i m stuck at the first step.

Comment: what's to stop someone from figuring out what this token is and simply typing it into their browser?

Comment: If the token is à hash of the paramèters,  it s safe